# How to create tasks with different concurrencies in Celery?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

The following tasks have different requirements. The `slow` task is supposed to get executed only one after another. The `fast` task can do the same (or more), but should be independent to the `slow` task.

I bound them to different queues, still the global concurrency works for both. If its `1` then a task gets either pulled from one of the two queues, or if it is `>1`, then the slow task can have more than one executions which it shouldn't.

```
@app.task
def slow(x, y):
    # slow operation, only one at a time with concurrency of 1
    heavy_operation_takes_10_minutes()


@app.task
def fast(x, y):
    # can also be concurrency of 1 or more, as long as independent of `slow` task
    # ...
    return x + y
```

Is this possible with Celery?

Comment: You can implement locking, you can call the slow task as part of a chain... How and why are you calling these tasks?

Comment: I thought about that too, but locking would pull tasks from the queue, which could be executed by other workers in the meantime.

Comment: In the worst case the `slow` task function gets executed **N**-times where **N-1** are locked, and the `fast` task is still waiting to get one

Comment: If you have a solid locking mechanism that only allows for 1 task to acquire the lock at a time you can "retry" the task that doesn't acquire the lock which would put it back in the queue

Comment: Not a bad idea actually, but a push to the end of the queue is not recommended for my task. I am not 100% bound to the order, but it's recommended in my case if the order is not completely off

Comment: If you have dedicated workers for your slow task, they could wait for the lock to be released rather than retrying

Comment: Do you have a link or keyword how I can avoid that they “retry”?

Comment: If you must avoid putting the task to the back of the queue - "retrying". Then waiting for the lock would be your best bet

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to put tasks to different queues (which you already did, as I understand), and then run two different celery workers to listen these queues, with different concurrency. For example:

```
# non-concurrent worker for slow tasks
celery worker -A proj -Q queue-for-slow-tasks --concurrency=1 
# concurrent worker for fast tasks
celery worker -A proj -Q queue-for-fast-tasks
```

Comment: Unfortunately that would result in two processes. It seems I can't get around this, and maybe should even consider `os.fork()` for this

Comment: Yes, it is two separate processes. Why is it a problem?

Comment: I want to use the `fast` message to send infos that the already running `slow` task should be cancelled

Comment: How you are going to do that? Using `revoke` - https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.revoke ? It is ok to run workers in different processes, - they communicate via message broker, and revoke should work ok.